# non-laptop thin client for lap?

Tags: laptop, keyboard-video-mouse

Yea I know its a weird question title, but what I am looking for is something like a KVM that you would see in a server rack, only to server as a laptop kind of device.  I am imagining having a computer on the floor and the KVM device with a screen and keyboard/mouse sitting on my lap.  Anyone know if such a device exists???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have an existing laptop, then you could consider a [KVM2USB solution](http://www.epiphan.com/products/frame-grabbers/kvm2usb/?gclid=CLPWlej7u4oCFQImUAodVUsXPg.) by Epiphan Systems.

Although it is $399, you have to consider that purchasing some kind of "laptop kvm" type of device would probably be at least, if not *more* expensive.  Consider how much rack mounted KVM displays go for.

[image: KVM2USB PS/2]
<sub>(source: [epiphan.com](http://www.epiphan.com/images/img/foto/diagram_08_kvm2usb.png))</sub>

[image: KVM2USB USB]
<sub>(source: [epiphan.com](http://www.epiphan.com/images/img/foto/diagram_08a_kvm2usb.png))</sub>

Comment: ...awesome stuff

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be [VNC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing). It can cost less than a hardware solution, but would require installation on the server as well as the laptop. One advantage would be that it works over the network which would allow remote access, if needed, but with the requirement that additional security issues might need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

They are called rackmount kvms. Most of them includes keyboards and monitors and occupies 1U / 2U  at rack. 
Just google for rackmount kvm / rackmount monitor.

They are not cheap, starting from ~1000 USD.

Answer (score 0):

Would a remote desktop session not suffice for this?
you could use an existing laptop, even a lower powered one and just 'remote' into the other machines

this would work in a windows, mac or linux world, and unless your trying to run 3d games most modern media should work fine on a LAN connection (or even WiFi)

I use my HP Mini1000 to connect to my Corei7 systems and apart from the tiny screen the Mini1000 has things work nice and quick, anything I do in the session is performed on the big rig, not the laptop, the laptop just serves as a gateway